# T-SQL to find rows with at least one specific column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Data set

```
Key           Stage     balance   ForeignKey
---------------------------------------------
11805008       ABC         50      123
11805008       DEF          0      123  
14567898       DEF        100      456
```

Query so far

```
Select key, two.Stage, two.balance 
from table_a one, table_b two
where one.ForeignKey = two.foreignKey
```

I am looking for keys, stage and balance where key has stage of ABC and others. If key does not have stage ABC then it should not return any row for that key. But if that key has 'ABC' stage then it should return all rows for that key

```
Key           Stage     balance   ForeignKey
11805008       ABC        50       123
11805008       DEF        0        123
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IN clause to get all of the keys that have at least one stage of ABC.  Also, use a more modern inner join syntax.

```
SELECT one.key, two.Stage, two.balance
FROM table_a one
INNER JOIN table_b two ON one.ForeignKey = two.foreignKey
WHERE key IN (
  SELECT key
  FROM table_a
  INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.ForeignKey = table_b.foreignKey
  WHERE table_b.stage = 'ABC')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you can do this using window functions:

```
select key, stage, balance
from (Select key, two.Stage, two.balance,
             sum(case when two.stage = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by key) as num_abc
      from table_a one join
           table_b two
           on one.ForeignKey = two.foreignKey
     ) t
where num_abc > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select key, two.Stage, two.balance 
from table_a one
inner join table_b two
on one.foreignKey = two.foreignKey
where exists (
  select 1 from table_b x 
  where  x.foreignKey=one.foreignKey
  and x.Stage='ABC' )
```

I can only assume what your original data is. The statement works on my demo, see here: http://rextester.com/SUTS17842

Comment: Does not work. It only results row with x.stage = 'ABC'